# MySQL UNIQUE KEY based on referenced table column

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following tables representing a three-level constrained relation:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `number` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `chapters_book_id_number_uk` (`book_id`,`number`),
  CONSTRAINT `chapters_book_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chapter_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `number` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pages_chapter_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`chapter_id`) REFERENCES `chapters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Similar to how `chapters.number` is unique to the given book (ie, no more than one "Chapter 1" in a book), I'd like `pages.number` to be unique *to the given book*.

Does MySQL offer any way to build a `UNIQUE KEY` with reference to a column in a table that there must be connection to? ie.:

```
UNIQUE KEY `pages_book_id_number_uk` (`chapter`.`book_id`,`number`)
```

I do realize I can include `book_id` in the `pages` table, itself, but I'd prefer to avoid that as it's logically redundant and exposes a data integrity problem if `chapters.book_id` and `pages.book_id` were to somehow fall out of sync.

Fiddle of it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c7a9

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only way is to include `book_id` in pages. To avoid any integrity issues, you'll have to add a UNIQUE constraint (or change the PK) in `chapters`:  `UNIQUE (book_id, id)` and then have the FK defined from pages as `FOREIGN KEY (book_id, chapter_id) REFERENCES chapters (book_id, id)`.

Another possibility is to get rid of `chapters (id)` and `pages (chapter_id)` columns completely and reference the available `UNIQUE (book_id, number)`.

With the second option, your design can be:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `book_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `chapter_number` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`, `chapter_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `chapters_book_id_fk` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) 
      REFERENCES `books` (`id`) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `chapter_number` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_number` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`book_id`, `page_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `pages_chapter_id_fk` 
      FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`, `chapter_number`) 
      REFERENCES `chapters` (`book_id`, `chapter_number`) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm tackling other problems now but might circle back to give that first alternative a crack. The second would deviate too far from our conventions for my liking.

Comment: @Rikaelus - If the convention is that every table must have a `BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT`, I will protest on the grounds of inefficiency.  It becomes especially bad for a many-to-many mapping table.

Comment: @RickJames Basically that; many frameworks expect and even require a single-column unique ID, though Laravel (which I'm using here) thankfully doesn't require them for many-to-many mapping tables. As a rule I prefer a clean delineation between database design and software implementation but I'm trying to let Laravel take the lead on this one.